# Ricci tensor of direct product of manifolds

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

Imagine I have a (Lorentzian) manifold with a metric

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   g_{\mu\nu} &0\\
   0&g_{mn}\\
   \end{array} } \right]$

Will the Ricci tensor be also block diagonal without any mixing of the two manifolds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, you have a manifold comprising two manifolds, say $M = N \times R$, and the metric is written as $m_{ab} = n_{ab} + r_{ab}$ with $n_{ab}$ defined on $N$ and $r_{ab}$ on $R$. Since the $N$, $R$ are disjoint, if you define a tensor in, say, $N$, its local coordinates corresponding to $R$ are zero, hence the Ricci tensor etc are all block diagonal.